# Turn on/off mobile hotspot in android higher 8 by programming

Tags: android, hotspot

I want to turn on or off mobile hotspot via code. I read many tutorials, but I see that it only works with API version lower 26. And I see the function

```
wifiManager.setWifiApEnabled
```

It uses for turning on or off mobile hotspot. But it is not existed in Api version higher. Is there any replace for it?

```
        WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();
        wifiConfiguration.SSID = "Hotspot";
        wifiConfiguration.preSharedKey = "Password123";
        wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);

        // Enable hotspot
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false); // Disable Wi-Fi
        wifiManager.setWifiApEnabled(wifiConfiguration, true); // setWifiApEnabled is not existed in api verion higher
```

I wonder why tasker app or macrodroid can turn on or turn off the hotspot.